# Configurable ucollectionview keeps repeating data loaded from json

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4, uistepper

I'm trying to configure a uicollectionview based on the stepper value on the settings containerview but it's showing the same first data in the uicollectionviewcell received from json repeatedly when it supposed to just hide or show the column or row of the the uicollectionview based on the stepper value on the settings containerview.

```
  func updatemimicrowcolumns() -> Void {

    // subtract the number of colums (for the 1-pt spacing between cells), and divide by number of columns
    let w = (mimic1colview.frame.size.width - CGFloat((columncountcg - 1))) / CGFloat(columncountcg)

    // subtract the number of rows (for the 1-pt spacing between rows), and divide by number of rows
    let h = (mimic1colview.frame.size.height - CGFloat((rowcountcg - 1))) / CGFloat(rowcountcg)

    // reload the collection view
    mimic1colview.reloadData()

}




func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return rowcountcg

}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return columncountcg

    }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = mimic1colview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "colcell", for: indexPath) as! MimicCell1

    let getDesc = desc[safe: indexPath.row]
    let getVal = valu[safe: indexPath.row]
    let getNum = state[safe: indexPath.row]
    let devName = dev[safe: indexPath.row]

    if getNum == "2"
    {
        statmsg = "Normal"
        cell.devdes1.text = getDesc
        cell.devvalue1.text = getVal
        cell.devstate1.text = statmsg
        cell.devname1.text = devName
        cell.devstate1.textColor = UIColor.green

    }
    else if getNum == "3"
    {
        statmsg = "Alarm"
        cell.devdes1.text = getDesc
        cell.devvalue1.text = getVal
        cell.devstate1.text = statmsg
        cell.devname1.text = devName
        cell.devstate1.textColor = UIColor.red


    }


       return cell

}
```

added print value in getnum:

> ["2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2"] ["2", "2", "3",
>   "2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2"] ["2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2",
>   "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3"] ["2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3",
>   "2", "2", "2", "3", "2"] ["2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2",
>   "2", "2", "3", "2", "3"] ["2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2",
>   "2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2"] ["2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3",
>   "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3"] ["2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2",
>   "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3"] ["2", "2", "3",
>   "2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3",
>   "2"]

Comment: There might be something wrong in your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`, which is responsible for your content at each cell.

Comment: There's nothing wrong as it loads normally without repeating if the numberOfItemsInSection is stringarray.count if it is non-configurable. @antonio081014

Comment: Your `numberOfItemsInSection` returns the same row count for every section??

Comment: @MikeTaverne numberOfItemsInSection it does not repeat and all the json data is shown normally without repetition provided the section is set to 1.

Comment: I think it’s better if you could post all your UICollectionView datasource methods

Comment: @antonio081014 I'll post it. wait.

Comment: @antonio081014 edited already.

Comment: can you print out getNum value in cellFoRow method?

Comment: @tereks the value is ["2"]
["2", "2"]
["2", "2", "3"]
["2", "2", "3", "2"]
["2", "2", "3", "2", "3"]
["2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2"]
["2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3"]
["2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3"]
["2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2"]

Comment: So you get only 2 and 3. Now you check other values - they must be different.

Comment: They are the values that are tied to each value, 2 indicates a status normal and 3 indicates that it's triggered, is there something wrong with my array? @tereks